# Event to listen to attribute changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I don't think this is possible but maybe someone knows a way to achieve this. I want to attach an event to an html element to listen to attribute change. So say for instance that I want something to happen when a visibility of a div changes. The reason is that I have no control over the JavaScript that is switching the visibility, hence the need for an event.

Comment: I think you are looking to listen to the DOMAttrModified event?

Comment: Thanks!! You want to put that as an answer so I can +1 ? Thanks Again

Comment: DOMAttrModified is only for attributes though; it wouldn't fire if a stylesheet or context change affected the visibility. Also it's not available in all browsers. For compatibility, you would have to use a poller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This jquery plugin might be interesting as it monitors the mentioned event in the jquery way:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx