# jquery event listener on checkbox disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently looking for an event listener for input type=checkbox that fires when disable state changes

1. any trigger changes disable state of any checkbox on the site
2. event listener for state change fires

I do not want to add the event to the first trigger which changes the checkbox state. It must be independent, for the trigger may change.

What I have tried so far:

```
$(function(){
      $('.trigger').live('click', function(){            
          $('.eventbox').attr('disabled','disabled');
      });


      $('.eventbox').live('change', function(){
          alert('state changed');
      });
 });
```

Unfortunately change doesn't work.

thank you for your help.
jesse

Comment: Do you mean "disable" or "checked" state?

Comment: how do you disable the checkbox? do you use the `.button('disable')`?

Comment: change only tracks if checkbox is checked or not checked, i.e. alteration of those two. Are you sure you want to track if checkbox is enabled/disabled? Sorry for repeated question, but I want to be sure :)

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240592/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-changes-to-an-objects-attributes-in-javascript

Comment: looks quite promising, but didn't work with:
$('body').change(function(event){
   event = event || window.event; 
   console.log(event.target);
   console.log(event.srcElement);
 });

it always shows the click event, but not the attribute changes

Comment: this indeed looks good: https://www.adaptavist.com/display/jQuery/Mutation+Events

Answer (score 0):

can you put a trigger on the thing that does the checkbox disabling?  By that I mean, if you have some button that as a side effect disables some checkboxes on click, could you tack you listener onto the click of the button?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your answer. I do not want to add something to the trigger, for it may change or other triggers may cause disabling of a checkbox. These other triggers may not be click events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you really want to track checking/unchecking of checkbox and not enabling/disabling.

```
$(function(){
      $('.trigger').live('click', function(){            
          $('.eventbox').removeAttr('checked');
      });


      $('.eventbox').live('change', function(){
          alert('state changed');// this will be fired only if state was checked
      });
 });
```

Comment: sorry ivan, but i do not want checking/unchecking. i want disabling of checkboxes. as i wrote.

Comment: Ok. I asked you in original post :) You did not answer so I took liberty to interpret :D

Comment: no problem :)
by the way: even on check/uncheck the change event does not work

Comment: I investigated this a bit and there are some solutions but I do not like them :) Check this links: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844018/event-to-listen-to-attribute-changes